Scala Native + AKKA HTTP issue
I would like to use Scala Native for my backend server to run some code, which are writen in C.
But when I enabled the scala native plugin in the build.sbt, I got errors during nativeLink.
my build.sbt looks like this:
    lazy val akkaHttpVersion = "10.6.0"
    lazy val akkaVersion     = "2.9.0"


    resolvers += "Akka library repository".at("https://repo.akka.io/maven")

    enablePlugins(
        JavaAppPackaging,
        DockerPlugin)



    fork := true
    dockerBaseImage := "adoptopenjdk:11-jre-hotspot"
    dockerExposedPorts ++= Seq(8080, 8080)
    lazy val root = (project in file(".")).
        settings(
            inThisBuild(List(
                organization    := "fev.io",
                scalaVersion    := "2.13.12"
            )),
        name := "miniuptane",
        libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
            "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-http"                % akkaHttpVersion,
            "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-http-spray-json"     % akkaHttpVersion,
            "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor-typed"         % akkaVersion,
            "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-stream"              % akkaVersion,
            "ch.qos.logback"    % "logback-classic"           % "1.2.11",

            "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-http-testkit"        % akkaHttpVersion % Test,
            "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor-testkit-typed" % akkaVersion     % Test,
            "org.scalatest"     %% "scalatest"                % "3.2.12"        % Test,
            "org.scala-lang"    %% "toolkit"                  % "0.1.7",
            "com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick" % "3.4.1",
      
            "com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick-hikaricp" % "3.4.1",
            "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.34"
        )
    )
 
    enablePlugins(ScalaNativePlugin)  
    import scala.scalanative.build._

    nativeConfig ~= {
        _.withLTO(LTO.thin)
        .withMode(Mode.releaseFast)
        .withGC(GC.commix)
    }

compile of scala code has no problem. But when I run in sbt, the nativeLink returns following error

Unknown type akka.http.scaladsl.marshalling.PredefinedToResponseMarshallers, referenced from:
...
(Compile / nativeLink) Unreachable symbols found after classloading run. It can happen when using dependencies not cross-compiled for Scala Native or not yet ported JDK definitions.

this error is only one example, I got a lot of similar errors. it seems like the akkt http cannot run if the scala native plugin enabled. if it is not enabled, there is no such error

I would be shocked if Akka worked with Scala native, given that it does make use of some fairly JVM-specific APIs.

I decide to switch to JNI to solve the problem
